# Pass JavaScript variable from one function to the other?

Tags: javascript, scope

```
  var pageBefore;
  $("#demo").dragend({
    onSwipeStart: function() { var pageBefore = this.page; console.log(pageBefore); },
    jumpToPage: 2,
    onSwipeEnd: function() {
        var pageNow = this.page;                                    

        console.log(pageBefore);
        console.log(pageNow);
```

I'm trying to pass `var pageBefore` to the function from `onSwipeEnd` but its empty there. What can I do to pass the variable pageBefore inside the `onSwipeEnd` function?

Comment: Remove the `var` inside the `onSwipeStart`. You don't want a local variable, you want to affect the outer one.

Comment: to use global variable just don't use var in function.